# Get image width and height before loading them

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I'm using Universal Image Loader library to download my images from internet.

Is it possible to get images size before loading them to set my layout prams to desired values?

Something like `inJustDecodeBounds` property, Any ideas?

Comment: Are you suggesting you want to get the image's dimensions before it's even loaded?

Comment: @angelsl Yes but It's not a suggestion, It's a question!

Comment: How are you intending to do that? I've just skimmed through the library and I don't think it supports parsing an image's header before it's fully loaded to get dimensions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting from the documentation @ https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

How UIL define Bitmap size needed for exact ImageView? It searches defined parameters?

1. Get actual measured width and height of ImageView.
2. Get android:layout_width and android:layout_height parameters.
3. Get android:maxWidth and/or android:maxHeight parameters.
4. Get maximum width and/or height parameters from configuration (memoryCacheExtraOptions(int, int) option).
5. Get width and/or height of device screen.

**So try to set android:layout_width|android:layout_height** or **android:maxWidth|android:maxHeight parameters for ImageView if you know approximate maximum size of it**. It will help correctly compute Bitmap size needed for this view and save memory.

You cannot get the image height and width before the image is downloaded. You can set the imageview height and width.

Answer (score 1):

Stream the image file into a `BitMap` object.  Then use `getHeight` and `getWidth`.

Adjust the View accordingly then draw the `BitMap` to it.

Answer (score 0):

If the images are coming from a location that you control, why not have an XML file with each images file name, or a unique identifier like:

```
<?xml version="1.0">
<images>
    <image filename="image01.png">
        <attrs width="400" height="500"/>
    </image>
    <image filename="image02.png">
        <attrs width="700" height="450"/>
    </image>
</images>
```

Store this file in the same location of the images, and download it first. Then set the values by using the width and height stored in the XML file.

Note: Answer based on assumption that they are your images, as you said "my images".